# How to display comments coming from Redux store on individual component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created a basic single page app, on initial page there is some dummy data and on click of each item I direct user to individual details page of that item. I wanted to implement comment and delete comment functionality which I successfully did but now when I comment or delete the comment it doesn't only happen at that individual page but in every other page too. Please see the sandbox example for better clarify.

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-feistel-g62g0?file=/src/components/ProductDetails.js

So once you add some comments in individual page, go back and then click to another products, apparently you will see that the comments you've done in other pages are also available there. What do you think causing this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own logical solution. You probably might find a better solution but this works pretty well too. I thought of passing another property in the object with the params I get from url and then filter the comments by their url params. So that I could do filtering based on the url parameters and display the comments only made on that specific page.

So `ProductDetails.js` page should be looking like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Input, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const ProductDetails = (props) => {


    const [commentObject, setCommentObject] = useState({
        text: "",
        date: "",
        id: ""
    });

    const clickHandler = () => {
        if (!commentObject.text.trim()) {
            return
        }
        props.addNewComment(commentObject)
        setCommentObject({
            ...commentObject,
            text: ""
        })
        console.log(commentObject.id);
    }
    useEffect(() => {

    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {props.posts ? props.posts.text : null}

            {props.comments.filter(comment => {
                return comment.postId === props.match.params.slug
            }).map(({ text, id }) => {

                return (<div key={id}>
                    <p>{text}</p>
                    <Button onClick={() => props.deleteComment(id)} >Delete comment</Button></div>)
            })}
            <Input value={commentObject.text}
                onChange={comment => setCommentObject({ text: comment.target.value, date: new Date(), id: Date.now(), postId: props.match.params.slug })}
            />
            <Button onClick={clickHandler} >Add comment</Button>

        </div>
    );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

    let slug = ownProps.match.params.slug;


    return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.find(post => post.slug === slug),

    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addNewComment: (object) => { dispatch({ type: "ADD_COMMENT", payload: { comment: { text: object.text, date: object.date, id: object.id, postId: object.postId } } }) },
        deleteComment: (id) => { dispatch({ type: "DELETE_COMMENT", id: id }) }
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

The same state being reused by all the different pages.

Try to load dynamically load reducers for each page/router differently to use distinct state values.

You can start from here

[Redux modules and code splitting](http://nicolasgallagher.com/redux-modules-and-code-splitting/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The documentation is really hard to understand for me. I couldn't make sense out of it.  Can you maybe make a clear explanation or suggest another documentation to read?

Comment: Cool, let me try find different tutorial...but the basic problem is this same state is being reused, since you are using the same component.